# How can be a mobile application stacked with firebase/node.js Back-End along with Flutter for Front-End?

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, development-environment

I am making a Mobile app using Firebase and Flutter but I want to write the backend in node.js and UI on Flutter.

I need help in Setting up Dev Environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have knowledge of cloud function to implement backend using firebase.

Comment: I found out that cloud functions are basically used to design applications that are event-driven as well as are massively scalable without any prior/apt knowledge of infrastructure.